# redhat satellite + falback procedure - how

Tags: linux, yum, rpm, redhat-satellite

I used the RHN -  red-hat satellite version 5.x in order to install errata patch: ( on linux version 6.x )

```
glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64
```

while the curent patch on my linux was

glibc-devel-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64

so after RHN installation the patch installed successfully

but I want now to return to the previous patch version -

```
 glibc-devel-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64
```

How RHN can do the fallback process?

what are the steps that ended from RHN in order to perform the fallback?

.
.
.

from my linux machine:

```
# yum history info | tail -5
    Updated glibc-devel-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64   @rhel-x86_64-server-6
    Update              2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64   @rhel-x86_64-server-6
    Updated glibc-headers-2.12-1.166.el6_7.3.x86_64 @rhel-x86_64-server-6
    Update                2.12-1.166.el6_7.7.x86_64 @rhel-x86_64-server-6
    history info
```

Comment: Have you tried the yum downgrade command?

Comment: I want to do the downgrde from RHN

Comment: Nevertheless, you did not answer the question from @fpmurphy1. See also e.g. https://access.redhat.com/solutions/186763 or https://access.redhat.com/solutions/29617. RHN itself only supports rollback using snapshots, see https://access.redhat.com/solutions/24942

Answer (score 0):

You can go to:

*System Detail -> Packages -> Compare Package Profiles / Manage Package Profiles*

Here you can compare to another profile. Ideally to profile of the same system **before** you done the upgrade. But you can compare against some other machine too.
You can then sync to selected profiles, which can do the downgrade (and removal/installation too). You need *Provision* entitlement to do so.

Profiles can be created in:

*System Detail -> Packages -> Profiles*

yum downgrade from command line should work too as those old version of packages are present in the channel as well.